# Extract a string that spans across multiple lines - stringr

Tags: r, stringr

I need to extract a string that spans across multiple lines on an object.

The objetc:

```
> text <- paste("abc \nd \ne")
> cat(text)
abc 
d 
e
```

With str_extract_all I can extract all the text between ‘a’ and ‘c’, for example.

```
> str_extract_all(text, "a.*c")
[[1]]
[1] "abc"
```

Using the function ‘regex’ and the argument ‘multiline’ set to TRUE, I can extract a string across multiple lines. In this case, I can extract the first character of multiple lines.

```
> str_extract_all(text, regex("^."))
[[1]]
[1] "a"

> str_extract_all(text, regex("^.", multiline = TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "a" "d" "e"
```

But when I try the to extract "every character between a and d" (a regex that spans across multiple lines), the output is "character(0)".

```
> str_extract_all(text, regex("a.*d", multiline = TRUE))
[[1]]
character(0)
```

The desired output is:

**“abcd”**

How to get it with stringr?

Answer (score 3):

`dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data.frame(text) %>%
  mutate(new = lapply(str_extract_all(text, "(?!e)\\w"), paste0, collapse = ""))
         text   new
1 abc \nd \ne  abcd
```

Here we use the character class `\\w`, which does not include the new line metacharacter `\n`. The negative lookahead `(?!e)` makes sure the `e` is not matched.

`base R`:

```
unlist(lapply(str_extract_all(text, "(?!e)\\w"), paste0, collapse = ""))
[1] "abcd"
```

Comment: Thank you. The desired output is "abcd” (from a do d), and not "“abcde”. But your output can be directed to str_extract_all.

Comment: Please see updated solution

Comment: Thank you. To get the desired output you don't need to put the string inside a dataframe and manipulate it with mutate. This also works:
text %>%
  str_extract_all("(?!e)\\w")
The only problem is that this way you are not extracting the caracters between 'a' and 'd'.  Your are NOT extracting what is before 'e'.
Please see my solution.

Comment: Afraid your take is incorrect: "Your are NOT extracting what is before 'e'." What this `(?!e)\\w` does is the negative lookahead disallows the character class `\\w` to match if the character is a `e`. And have you seen the base R solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
str_remove_all(text,"\\s\\ne?")
[1] "abcd"
```

OR

```
paste0(trimws(strsplit(text, "\\ne?")[[1]]), collapse="")
[1] "abcd"
```

Comment: Thank you. The desired output is "abcd” (from a do d), and not "“abcde”. But your output can be directed to str_extract_all.

Comment: sorry I missed that, but I've edited it

Comment: Thank you. You pointed me to the best solution (for me). First remove line breaks, and then match the desired regex.
Please see my solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

In base R to get the desired output `abcd`:

```
text <- gsub("[\r\n]|[[:blank:]]", "", text)

substr(text,1, nchar(text)-1)
```

```
[1] "abcd"
```

**First answer:**
We can use `gsub`:

```
gsub("[\r\n]|[[:blank:]]", "", text)
```

```
[1] "abcde"
```

Comment: Thank you. The desired output is "abcd” (from a do d), and not "“abcde”. But your output can be directed to str_extract_all.

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: Thank you. You pointed me to the best solution (for me). First remove line breaks, and then match the desired regex.
Please see my solution.

Answer (score 1):

The anwers above remove line breaks. So, a two step approach can work to get the desired output 'abcd'.

1 - Use `str_remove_all` or `gsub` to remove the line breaks (in this case, also removing blank spaces).

2 - Use `str_extract_all` to get the desired output ('abcd' in this case).

```
> text %>% 
+   str_remove_all("\\s\\n") %>% 
+   str_extract_all("a.*d")
[[1]]
[1] "abcd"
```

Short regex reference:

\n - new line (return)
\s - any whitespace
\r - carriage return